# Force browsers to close TCP connections on refresh

Tags: browser, tcp, page-refresh, keep-alive

I am developing an embedded web server. If I enable keep-alive, then every time I unplug, re-flash, and replug the server, the Chrome/Firefox refresh buttons don't work, because the browser tries to re-use a connection that was not established since the last server boot.

Curl does not have this problem, because it automatically creates a new connection every time you call it (even if using keep-alive).

I know I could turn off keep-alive, or have the server send TCP reset packets in response to data segments on non-existing connections. But those hacks have their own issues. Having the browser automatically reset its connections when I click refresh would seem a lot more logical. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The problem here is your TCP stack, not your server. Your TCP stack should be issuing RSTs on the refresh requests, as the connections don't exist any more. The server itself can't do that, as it doesn't see those requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Having the browser automatically reset its connections when I click refresh would seem a lot more logical.

I don't think this would be more logical. Instead of fixing a single server by having a properly behaving TCP stack (i.e. send RST for non-existing connections [RFC 793 #3.4 'Reset generation'](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.4)) you expect a change in every client which might connect to the server.

Given that Chrome and Firefox are open source you can change the source code of it and install it on all affected clients. But there is as far as I know no setting in these browsers to change the behavior in a way you want. And then are also other browsers which you would need to change to and roll out these changes to all clients - this just does not scale.

Comment: TLDR: the TCP stack SHOULD send the RST in this case. OK you're right. Somehow I missed that when I wrote the TCP stack. (and also thought maybe that sending RST in such cases could cause some kind of relay attack... I guess it can't) Thank you. Please add a reference like https://www.pico.net/kb/what-is-a-tcp-reset-rst and I will accept.

Comment: Added the reference myself and accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my TCP stack to send RST in response to non-existing connections. Note that the ACK flag must also be set, and the SEQ/ACK fields must exactly mirror what was received.Then it works beautifully! The browser refresh is always fast (typically instantaneous),  even if the server was abruptly rebooted. Thank you.

Comment: I am surprised that the browser doesn't even display anything in the console when the RST is sent to it... this must be a very very common situation.

Comment: @personal_cloud You should not desecrate Steffen's correct answer by citing a third-party reference. The only acceptable reference is the TCP RFC.